# Side and angle relations in a hyperbolic quadrilateral.

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $PQRS$ be hyperbolic quadrilateral, i.e. a quadrilateral in $\mathbb{H}$ whose sides are hyperbolic geodesic. Let length$(PQ)=l_1$, and length$(PS)=l_2.$ Also $\angle SPQ=\theta_1$,  $\angle PSR=\theta_2$, and $\angle PQR=\theta_3.$ It can be proved that $PQRS$ is uniquely determined by $l_1,l_2,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3.$ Suppose $\theta_i\neq\pi/2$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

**Q) Determine a closed formula for $\angle QRS$, length$(QR)$ and length$(SR)$.**

PS: 1) I want a closed formula, not a number of equations from where it can be derived.

2) Angles are not $\pi/2.$ So formulas for Saccheri quadrilateral will not work.

3) Any kind of references (except "The geometry of discrete groups" by Beardon and "Foundations of hyperbolic geometry" by Ratcliffe) will be helpful.

Comment: With (hyperbolic triangle) SAS you can calculate SQ in the triangle SPQ, , and then with (hyperbolic triangle) ASA you can calculate SR and QR in the triangle RQS. - 

 Martins "Foundations of geometry and the non euclidean plane " says a bit about your problem on pages 421-434, but if you understand Radcliffe's " "Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds"  I don't think this book will teach you anything. (Radcliffes level is just much higer) also in other more advanced hyperbolic  geometry books contain these formulas